# first time sync of documents etc

Tags: sync

I have just started Ubuntu one free and also signed up to Ubuntu One music streaming. I have set my documents, music and pictures folders to sync with Ubuntu One. All the folders are marked as synced, but not all the files in them have been synced. How do I (a) check was has been properly synced and (b) make sure every file in each folder is synced?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the file that you have synced on the website: https://one.ubuntu.com/

**EDIT**

All the information of the ubuntu one daemon are available with the command `u1sdtool`. In particular

```
u1sdtool --waiting
u1sdtool --waiting-metadata
u1sdtool --waiting-content
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I find that a file has not synced, what do I do then? Also, do I have to go through all my files and check the synchronisation of each one individually?

Comment: If a file has not synced after a day it is a software bug. You can try to force it restarting the ubuntu one daemon with `u1sdtool --quit` and `u1sdtool --start`.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you mean that I should paste those statements into   the terminal? Do I run one and then the other or do I run them both at once?

Comment: One at once. If they return nothing there is no more file in sync queue.

Comment: This is what happened:ajhc3758@ajhc3758-laptop:~$ u1sdtool --quit
ubuntuone-syncdaemon stopped.
ajhc3758@ajhc3758-laptop:~$ u1sdtool --start
ajhc3758@ajhc3758-laptop:~$